Why on ios device i connect to socks5 proxy via shadowrocket and it doesn't work?
I am using Smartproxy and through https everything works fine, but as soon as I connect socks5 then no pages work, even though I am using shadowrocket.I understand that socks5 doesn't work directly with ios.
